# How to add other images as TIFF overviews?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdaladdo, map-overviews

TIFF files can contain overviews for quicker loading/displaying at small scales (=more "zoomed out").

These can be generated and added with GDAL's `gdaladdo` command. `gdaladdo` will compute the overviews by summarizing blocks of pixels as individual pixels. (Thus why the overviews are also sometimes called "pyramids".) This makes sense for orthophotography or for scalar-raster-geodata-encoded-as-image TIFFs (e.g. a DEM), but if the TIFF is a map, I think it might be more suitable to use smaller-scale (=more "zoomed out") maps (if available) as overviews that has e.g. a lower level of detail, omits some features and has captions that are still readable at that display size.

Is there a way to use separate images to create the overviews to be included in a TIFF, maybe even with GDAL command line tools?

Would doing so break any overview use-cases or tools that are also relevant for maps?

Comment: Interesting concept... I don't think anyone has done this before in a static raster. Are you suggesting dropping of details from the map like lesser roads and smaller cities as the pyramids are built? It's a good idea for a narrow selection of rasters, perhaps you could put that in as a request with GDAL http://gdal.org/

Comment: For sure it has been done, for example here http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Does-geoserver-support-multiple-overview-files-for-one-GeoTIFF-td5362344.html. The key seems to be to generate the tiff files of suitable size and name them as some.tiff.ovr, some.tiff.ovr.ovr and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

I just tried this with a 1:100K raster topographic map and 1:250K and 1:1m topos as the "overviews".  Works fine.

First I ensured each raster had the same extent.

Then on Windows I had to resort to renaming the smaller scale tiffs to "topo100k.tiff.ovr" and "topo100k.tiff.ovr.over", etc. as I didn't want to install [ImageMagick or Irfanview to create multipage TIFFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916769/how-can-i-programmatically-build-a-multi-page-tiff-out-of-many-single-page-tiffs).

On Linux I was able to just use the [`tiffcp` utility](http://libtiff.maptools.org/man/tiffcp.1.html) to create a multipage TIFF to use as the overview file.

```
tiffcp topo250k.tif topo1m.tif topo100k.tif.ovr
```

---

**The result:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
> gdalinfo.exe topo100k.tif

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: topo100k.tif
       topo100k.tif.ovr
       topo100k.tif.ovr.ovr
       topo100k.tif.aux.xml
Size is 15911, 7912
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (146.287552142133137,-42.425406934716420)
Pixel Size = (0.000134582559863,-0.000134582559863)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 146.2875521, -42.4254069) (146d17'15.19"E, 42d25'31.46"S)
Lower Left  ( 146.2875521, -43.4902241) (146d17'15.19"E, 43d29'24.81"S)
Upper Right ( 148.4288953, -42.4254069) (148d25'44.02"E, 42d25'31.46"S)
Lower Right ( 148.4288953, -43.4902241) (148d25'44.02"E, 43d29'24.81"S)
Center      ( 147.3582237, -42.9578155) (147d21'29.61"E, 42d57'28.14"S)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=189.173, StdDev=44.290
  Overviews: 6692x3328, 2381x1184
Band 2 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=200.430, StdDev=45.143
  Overviews: 6692x3328, 2381x1184
Band 3 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=191.235, StdDev=57.065
  Overviews: 6692x3328, 2381x1184
```